# Array of objects containing objects to flat object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to convert an `array of objects containing objects` structure to an `objects in array` structure in JavaScript/Typescript.

Input:

```
[
  {
    "a": "Content A",
    "b": 
    {
      "1": "Content 1",
      "2": "Content 2"
    }
  },
  {
    "y": "Content Y",
    "x": 
    {
      "3": "Content 3",
      "4": "Content 4"
    }
  },

]
```

Expected output

```
[
  {a: "Content A", b: "Content 1"}, 
  {a: "Content A", b: "Content 2"},
  {y: "Content Y", x: "Content 3"},
  {y: "Content Y", x: "Content 4"}
]
```

Answer with both TS & JS would be awesome!

Comment: does it change every time the key?

Comment: Yes it does, but they're irrelevant for the output

Comment: At least post your attempts

Comment: @EdgarQuintero I would like to, but the code is completely out of context. It's a hook inside class-validator to serialize the errors. I tried to post the question as simple as possible to make sure it can benefit the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```js
const all = [
    {
      "a": "Content A",
      "b": 
      {
        "1": "Content 1",
        "2": "Content 2"
      }
    },
    {
      "y": "Content Y",
      "x": 
      {
        "3": "Content 3",
        "4": "Content 4"
      }
    },
];
console.log(all.reduce((prev, el) =>{
    let curr = Object.entries(el);
let k1 = curr[0][0];
let k2 = curr[1][0];
    Object.entries(curr[1][1]).forEach((o => {
        
        let obj ={}
        obj[k1] = curr[0][1];
        obj[k2] = o[1];
        prev.push(obj);
    }))
    return prev;
},[]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatMap` and `Object.entries`

```js
const output = (arr) =>
  arr.flatMap((item) => {
    const [key1, str] = Object.entries(item).find(
      ([, val]) => typeof val === "string"
    );
    const [key2, obj] = Object.entries(item).find(
      ([, val]) => typeof val === "object"
    );
    return Object.values(obj).map((value) => ({ [key1]: str, [key2]: value }));
  });

const data = [
  {
    a: "Content A",
    b: {
      "1": "Content 1",
      "2": "Content 2",
    },
  },
  {
    y: "Content Y",
    x: {
      "3": "Content 3",
      "4": "Content 4",
    },
  },
];

console.log(output(data))
```